# Keyword from not found where expected(oracle sql)

Tags: oracle11g

```
  CREATE TABLE table2 AS 
     (select *,
              min(nullif (("col1"),0)) over (partition by col2,col3,col4) as "col6",
              min(nullif("col5",0)) over (partition by col1,col2,col3,col4) as "col7"
        FROM table1);
```

I dont know whats the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the wildcard "*" for columns like that. Because you are adding additional columns, you need to list out all the columns ...

So if your table1 has columns "col1 and col2", then your query would be:

```
  CREATE TABLE table2 AS 
     (select col1, col2,
              min(nullif (("col1"),0)) over (partition by col2,col3,col4) as "col6",
              min(nullif("col5",0)) over (partition by col1,col2,col3,col4) as "col7"
        FROM table1);
```

Comment: You can use the wildcard if you qualify it with the table name (`select table1.*, ...`) or a table alias; but it's better to spell the columns out anyway.

Comment: True that ... With only 1 table, I didn't think to mention it :)